# remote powershell script issue for adding IP address as relay - exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2010

firstly just to say my powershell skills are limited so please be gentle ;-)...

So I've built 4 or 5 runbooks using  microsoft Orchestrator to essentially run some remote powershell scripts which do various simple exchange tasks, such as setting OutOfOffice reply, enabling mailboxes, creating shared mailboxes with various permissions etc.  I had been using the same basic connection structure/method for these which works fine, ie

```
$ExchangeCAS = "<CASServerName>"
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<CASServerNameFQDN>/PowerShell/
import-PSSession $Session
    <script body with exchange cmdlets>

remove-PSSession $Session
```

However, I'm trying to create an additional runbook  to automatically add IP addresses as relay to our 4 hub servers - its a pretty basic script (that I dug out/tweaked from internet) but its not working when run from Orchestrator.  It does work fine when I run it from the Powershell ISE on the server that has the Exchange Tools installed, and the fact that the other exchange (similar) scripts that do work would at least rule out any permissions issues for the Orchestrator service account executing the script. For reference below is the full script I'm trying to run from Orchestrator as a .Net Activity and am testing using the powershell ISE on orchestrator server:-

```
$ExchangeCAS = "<ExCAS>"
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<ExCASFQDN>/PowerShell/
import-PSSession $Session

# Get Receive Connectors to update
$listofIPs = Import-Csv \\<TargetSERVER>\d$\psscripts\MailboxRightsScript\scorch\AddIPlist.TXT 

$recCons= Get-ReceiveConnector | Where {$_.Name -match"Anonymous Relay"}


ForEach ($recCon in $recCons)
    {
    Write-Host "Updating", $recCon.Identity
    forEach($line in $listofIPs)
        {

        $recCon.RemoteIPRanges +=$line.IP
        }
    Set-ReceiveConnector $recCon -RemoteIPRanges $recCon.RemoteIPRanges
    }

remove-PSSession $Session
```

The error I can see from the Orchestrator server ISE is as below:

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "\Anonymous Relay" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.ReceiveConnector" to 
type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ReceiveConnectorIdParameter".

From trawling through some articles it seems this is an issue with how data is passed between local and remote powershell and 'hydration' of objects.  TBH a lot of the detail of those discussions is a bit over my head when it comes to powershell, so not wishing to be lazy would anyone be able to provide a powershell script solution based on what I was trying above which I can run as a .net activity from Orchestrator to add an IP address/addresses (prefer from input file) as relay.  It would be good to know if the solution is easily modified to remove an address as relay aswell.

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: Can you try it with the following Import-Module (Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber) -Global, instead of Import-PSSession

Comment: Hi there, so back to work after the weekend to try this and alas no joy...  When run I run your version from the ISE I can still see the same errors re converting the deserialized value as above.  Any other suggestions  - very happy to try anything to get it working...cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use server distinguish name. It will work

```
Set-ReceiveConnector $recCon.DistinguishName -RemoteIPRanges $recCon.RemoteIPRanges
```